# on click removing all elements in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have created a jquery dynamic elements showing As of now when ever I click on single elements it deletes all can anyone help me out why is this happening or is there a way it can be done if I click on 1 element it it will remove 1 only

```js
$(document).on("click", ".rmove", function() {
  $(".compraision").remove();
  $('#company_graph').show();
  $('#comparision_graph').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="comparision">
  <div class="compraision index_opt co_heading_area pos">
    <div class="co_info"><span class="float-left">AGIC</span>
      <p class="float-right">44%</p>
      <a class="rmove">Remove </a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="compraision index_opt co_heading_area pos">
    <div class="co_info"><span class="float-left">PSMC</span>
      <p class="float-right">44%</p>
      <a class="rmove">Remove</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="compraision index_opt co_heading_area pos">
    <div class="co_info"><span class="float-left">AGTL</span>
      <p class="float-right">44%</p>
      <a class="rmove">Remove </a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/hk0d5exr/)

Comment: @Satpal I am sorry I am new here I was trying to add the link but was giving me error I was stucked up for more then 20 minutes so I snipet fiddle link and it worked

Comment: You learnt the lesson :), I have created one for edit it if you like and also retracted the close vote

Comment: great thanks alot I checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find element which needs to remove instead of selecting all elements

```js
$(document).on("click", ".rmove", function() {
  $(this).closest(".compraision").remove();
  $('#company_graph').show();
  $('#comparision_graph').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="comparision">
  <div class="compraision index_opt co_heading_area pos">
    <div class="co_info"><span class="float-left">AGIC</span>
      <p class="float-right">44%</p>
      <a class="rmove">Remove </a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="compraision index_opt co_heading_area pos">
    <div class="co_info"><span class="float-left">PSMC</span>
      <p class="float-right">44%</p>
      <a class="rmove">Remove</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="compraision index_opt co_heading_area pos">
    <div class="co_info"><span class="float-left">AGTL</span>
      <p class="float-right">44%</p>
      <a class="rmove">Remove </a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @UsmanKhan use `.closest()` or `parent().parent()` or any other options available because only `.parent()` removes one most parent after clicking `.remove` ` <div class="compraision index_opt co_heading_area pos">` this div is remain as it is if you see in `DOM`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look. https://jsfiddle.net/hk0d5exr/5/
`$(this).parent().parent()` only access to the parent of the element clicked.
Let me know if help.
Cheers

Comment: confused why you have used parent ?

Comment: you are trigger the click in .rmove, that is inside .compraision. You want to click .rmove and remove()  the correct .compraision right?. If clicked an element, you can go trough parent child nodes. like from .rmove to .compraision with parent(). to remove the correct nodes.

Comment: @Roy okk `parent()` is also nice but it only removes parent not the wrapped `div` which is `.compraision` div as you can see in DOM it remains this div as it is after click `.remove` so it should be `parent().parent()` or `.closest()` would be nice idea doesn't it?

Comment: @Curiousdev Take a look closely, closest will work, parent().parent() don't.

Comment: Nono, you are right, my fault. It's parent().parent().

Comment: but i think `.closest()` would be better idea doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make your jquery like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".rmove", function() {
  $(this).parents(".compraision").remove();
  $('#company_graph').show();
  $('#comparision_graph').hide();
});
```